# Does Android Support Non-Encrypted Connection with SSLScoket/SSLEngine?

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, encryption, openssl

In my android app, I want to support an unencrypted connection with TLS/SSL using SSLSocket or SSLEngine with TLSv1.2. In this case, only authentication will be performed but the connection will remain non-private or unencrypted.

It can be achieved with other platforms like iOS, Windows, and Mac by simply enabling a null cipher suite i.e TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256, and TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, etc.

But unfortunately, Android doesn't allow any of them to configure with SSLParameters and throws IIlegalArgument Exception of Null Cipher not supported.

What is another way around? Can I configure any of the null ciphers and achieve an unencrypted connection?

Comment: What's the underlying issue? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @RichardHeap underlying issue is to establish an unencrypted TLS connection by configuring one of the null cipher suites, b/w Android app and server.

Comment: So you want the server authentication (check signed cert etc) but not the encryption? Or could you just use a plain socket?

Comment: The purpose of this unencrypted connection with TLS is to first authenticate the server and then continue with unencrypted communication. In this way, authenticity and integrity will be obtained but no worry about confidentiality. The plain socket doesn't provide authentication.